# How to use Jamf MDM Services for iOS devices?

Tags: ios, mdm, apple-business-manager

Question 1:
I want to manage iOS devices with **Jamf MDM Services**.
If anyone have implemented this please guide me how to do this.
I need help regarding registering and installing Jamf MDM to my iPhone devices.

Question 2:
Also can i manage existing iOS devices with **supervision** mode without help of '**Apple Configurator**'?

I have tried going through Jamf Documentation and it looks like i need to first buy plans to start with. So it would be helpful to get some insights before spending money.

Comment: You should reach out to JAMF sales. They can answer all of your questions.